# Is csUnit dead? If so, what are the living alternatives?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to find out how to get csUnit and VS2010/.NET 4 to play nice together. There's no mention of .NET 4 in the csUnit FAQ, which also seems very much out of date. I checked out the Yahoo user group, but can't find any user posts past March 2008 there.

Am I correct in assuming that csUnit is dead? In that case, what test framework have the users moved on to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Matthew Vines answer ([NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) and [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/)), I think [xUnit.Net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) is the 3rd active open source UnitTesting solution.

Consider [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [Rhino.Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) and [FakeItEasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/) as active Open Source Mocking frameworks.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, because xUnit might very well be my cup of tea.

Comment: As much as I like the ideas behind xUnit.net, I ended up picking NUnit anyway, because of the better documentation, better availability of examples etc. I might switch framework later, but for a beginner in the unit testing game, documentation and sample code are important.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) and [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) would be the big ones right now.

But here is a reasonably extensive list of options:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages

Comment: I checked out the wikipedia list, though many of those projects are dead by now. +1 for naming the big ones.